# Does using Active Record pattern cause significant memory bloat?

Tags: database, design-patterns, activerecord, memory-management, language-agnostic

I'm looking into the difference between the active record and data mapper design patterns.  One simple question that came to mind is that with the duplication of the persistence methods in each active record instance, wouldn't that lead to a lot of unnecessary memory usage?  Or is it negligible?

Comment: Duplication per instance of class, or do you mean `Person.find` and `Pet.find` and `Building.find`?

Comment: @cfeduke per instance of class.

Answer (score 1):

Object oriented programming languages methods typically exist at the class level, not the object level. Meaning that an object is an instance of a class, and when invoking (or sending, depending on the language) `object.foo` its actually referring back to the class and invoking the method there in the context of the object. (This can be accomplished in a number of different ways that I'm not qualified to write about in depth.)

Imagine the overhead of `ToString`/`toString`/`to_s` in popular languages if every instance of `Object` or its inheritors had a copy of the method!

So to answer your question, no there is no unnecessary memory usage with regards to methods present on the *classes* that comprise your Active Record classes.

Comment: That explains a lot.  I was unaware that this is how objects/classes generally worked internally.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that in some languages, like Ruby (and not too sure if there are others) `Class` inherits from `Object` making things a little weird, but the general concept of the dispatch table is still the same. It **does** mean however that some instances of a given class could potentially have different behavior though this isn't the norm.